# Dataframe apply passing row with header

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe `df`. I want to apply a function `myfun` to every row of it. But I would ideally like to use the header names of the dataframe in the function `myfun`. Wondering if this can be done without explicitly renaming columns in `myfun`. Thanks!

```
myfun() <- function(rowdf) {
    //statements

    if(rowdf$price > 1000){
        val = "high"
    } elseif(rowdf$num_floors > 3){
        val = "high"
    } else{
        val = "low"
    }
    return(val)
}

//df has columns price and num_floors
bld_vals = apply(df, 1, myfun)
```

Comment: Take out the dollar sign operator, `if(rowdf[['price']] > 1000)` etc...

Comment: `ifelse` is Vectorized, why not use that?

Comment: Your syntax is suspect btw

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you will have to change,

1. You can use "$" on a dataframe you are passing that way.
2. There is no need of apply for what you intent to do.

Follow the following code:

```
myfun <- function(rowdf,price,num_floors) {

val <- ifelse (rowdf[,price]>1000,"high",ifelse(rowdf[,num_floors]>3,"high","low"))

return(val)

}


df$val <- myfun(df,"price","num_floors")
```

Comment: Did you test your code on a real data set? If so, please show it. Hint: `if` can't handle a condition of length larger than 1.

Comment: @DavidArenburg can you check now ? I have edited the answer. Thanks for the Hint.